# Dell Inspirion 7567 with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dell

I'm looking for a new laptop. For now I have chosen this one:

**Dell Inspirion 7567**

- **CPU:** Intel Core i7-7700HQ
- **VIDEO:** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
- **RAM:** 16GB
- **SSD:** 256GB + HDD: 1TB
- **Display:** 15.6" 1920x1080
- **OS:** Ubuntu 16.04 (Pre-installed by manufacturer)

Unfortunately I am cannot found information about this laptop in Ubuntu Certified hardware page. I want to ask how it works with Ubuntu? Are there some big issues or everything works perfect?

Comment: Everything is **expected** to work fine. Install Nvidia drivers for graphics.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Dell 7567 in dual boot with windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I have not faced any issues. Everything works fine on the fresh install.